# VNC server on Debian laptop

Tags: linux, debian, vnc

I am trying to get a vnc server running on my old laptop, which has debian 10 freshly installed.
I installed `tigervnc-standalone-server`, and it runs and *almost* does what I want.

If I start VNC before I login to my laptop I can run vnc, and connection is great and I can use it. IF I turn on my laptop, login, do stuff on my laptop, then I can't start the vnc server as I get an XIO error:

```
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12004000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Jul  2 22:20:19 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5905
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":5"
      after 173 requests (173 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I **THINK** the problem is that it is using screen 0: "created VNC server for screen 0"
however, I start vncserver as:
 `vncserver -localhost no -display :5`

My `Xvnc-session` is unmodified, not sure what I would have to change here (if anything)

```
#! /bin/sh

test x"$SHELL" = x"" && SHELL=/bin/bash
test x"$1"     = x"" && set -- default

vncconfig -iconic &
"$SHELL" -l <<EOF
exec /etc/X11/Xsession "$@"
EOF
vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
```

I also tried setting xstartup like so:
`vncserver -localhost no -xstartup startxfce4 :5`
which then allows me to use BOTH my laptop and vnc, however whenever I try to open a program in vnc, it instead pops up on my laptop's display

TL;DR I want a persistent second desktop, that doesn't interfere with the display attached to the laptop itself, and it seems like it's not letting me do that

Comment: have you tried xrdp? I use it all the time

Comment: Please tell us how you start the server when you do not login and add the exact command that outputs the error message.

Comment: vncserver -localhost no -display :5